# Crystal Reports '"This field name not known" error, due to SQL object naming conflict

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, schema, field

We had a sudden failure of 5 reports (out of about 20) in a development environment where the report templates had not been touched, and the error when trying to preview these reports was the seemingly common "This field name is not known" error from Crystal.

I thought I would post the non-obvious problem we had, and the solution we discovered, since this seems to be one of many ways to get this error that someone else might get caught by.

We have been slowly improving our database and were moving old versions of database code objects into a "Cleanup" schema group, for deletion later.

It turned out that the Crystal templates tried to use the old versions of views in Cleanup and not the new ones in the original schema due to, we assume, some schema-unaware runtime name matching on Crystal's part.

For example, we had, say,

Cleanup.vGetLocations (which no longer works because it, for example, refers to a now-removed table)
and
Stores.vGetLocations (the new view that works with new tables)

Crystal seemed to find the old view and throw this "field name not known" error when it failed to successfully return data.

Our solution was easy: we also renamed the old objects in the Cleanup schema, adding "OLD" to the name, such as "Cleanup.vGetLocationsOLD".  The broken reports previews then immediately worked.

We're using Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Welcome Scott.  Thanks for sharing, but you are supposed to ask questions on Stack Overflow, not post tech articles. Users assume there is a question each post.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports is indicating that a field has been 1) removed from the data set or 2) renamed.